# Remove letter from string using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is part of a SQL Server stored procedure that we have

```
WHEN C.Room IS NOT NULL AND LTRIM(RTRIM(C.ROOM)) != '' 
               AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room))) <= 4
   THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(C.building)) + '-' + LEFT('0000', 4 - LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room)))) + LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room))
   ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(C.building)) + '-' + '0000'
END AS Location_ID
```

This returns the following result:

```
001-P211
```

I would like to remove the letter after the `-` to get:

```
001-211
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hint: `REPLACE`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just add the `'-'` your self, looking to your code

```
 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(C.building)) + '-' + LEFT('0000', 4 - LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room)))) + LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room))
   ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(C.building)) + '-' + '0000
```

So, remove `+ '-' +`.

If this is not the case, then you can use `REPLACE()` function as

```
REPLACE(<Your CASE expression here>, '-', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Some sample data and expected results would help clarify but, if I'm following you, it looks like this might get you what you're asking for.

I used some dummy data to test where building was always 001

```
Room   Result
P211   001-0211
P212   001-0212
P2123  001-0000
P21    001-0021
2142   001-2142
AB42   001-0042
```

I added a new CASE expression to your existing code to check for the presence of characters in the beginning of the room number. If they exist then we strip them (I wasn't sure if you always had 1 alpha character or could possibly have more, so I made it work for more). If they don't exist then it just uses the Room value as is. It won't strip letters at the end, so if you had a room P21A it would return 021A.

The third case in my example returns 0000 due to your `LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room))) <= 4` condition.

Also, you won't get 001-211 as you specifically use '0000' in your LEFT.

You can test it here: https://rextester.com/PUI69939

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT '001' AS Building, 'P211' AS Room
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '001 ' AS Building, 'P212 ' AS Room
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '001 ' AS Building, 'P2123' AS Room
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '001 ' AS Building, 'P21' AS Room
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '001 ' AS Building, '2142' AS Room
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '001 ' AS Building, 'AB42' AS Room
)

SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN C.Room IS NOT NULL AND LTRIM(RTRIM(C.ROOM)) != '' 
               AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room))) <= 4
   THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(C.building)) + '-' +  
        CASE 
            WHEN c.room LIKE '[a-z]%' THEN LEFT('0000', 4 -LEN(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room)),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',c.room),LEN(c.room)))) + SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room)),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',c.room),LEN(c.room))
            ELSE LEFT('0000', 4 -LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room)))) + LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room))
        END
   ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(C.building)) + '-' + '0000'
END AS Location_ID
 FROM  cte c
```

If you want results like...

```
Room   Result
P211   001-211
P212   001-212
P2123  001-0000
P21    001-21
2142   001-2142
AB42   001-42
```

...you can remove the LEFT logic so it looks like this

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN C.Room IS NOT NULL AND LTRIM(RTRIM(C.ROOM)) != '' 
               AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room))) <= 4
   THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(C.building)) + '-' +  
        CASE 
            WHEN c.room LIKE '[a-z]%' THEN SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room)),PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',c.room),LEN(c.room))
            ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room))
        END
   ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(C.building)) + '-' + '0000'
END AS Location_ID
 FROM  cte c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I removed - 

   WHEN C.Room IS NOT NULL AND LTRIM(RTRIM(C.ROOM)) != '' 
                   AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room))) <= 4
       THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(C.building)) + LEFT('0000', 4 - LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room)))) + LTRIM(RTRIM(c.room))
       ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(C.building))  + '0000'
    END AS Location_ID
```

Answer (score -1):

The code that you posted is part of a CASE statement. For the else case, what you are asking about will never happen due to direct concatenation:

> ltrim(rtrim(C.building)) + '-' + '0000' => Will always end with '-0000'

For the first case, we can get the character index of the letter after the '-' with the CHARINDEX function:

> CHARINDEX('-', *Target Expression* ) + 1

To remove the letter after '-' we can create two substrings, one to the left and another to the right of the letter and concatenate them together:

> LEFT( *Target Expression*, CHARINDEX('-', *Target Expression*)) + RIGHT (*Target Expression*, LEN(*Target Expression*) - (CHARINDEX('-', *Target Expression*) + 1) )